# Is there a router that does not break after 6 - 12 months?

Tags: router, wireless-router

I have owned many routers in my lifetime.  From the Cisco IOS 1200 (for tinkering), to linksys before it became cisco, D-Link and now my Belkin sitting on the floor.

I have noticed one problem with all my home router products.  They only last about 6 months.  Then, suddenly they start dropping connections, losing connections, etc.  Further, their support lifespan for firmware updates has been abysmal...sub 1 year...2 if I'm lucky.

So, have I just been having notoriously awful luck or are all home routers 180 days from the trash?  Is there a router that doesn't break after 6-12 months, doesn't need to be reset every day or even week and does not reach EOL while its practically still on the store shelves?

Sorry if I'm bitter.  But, this comes from years of putting up with total junk and horrible service.  I'm a programmer and a long time tech. junkie.  I know someone can build a good router.

Comment: This is a shopping recommendation question and is off topic.  Flagging for moderator to close.

Comment: I find that the really REALLY inexpensive models tend not to last very long.  I've had really good success with LinkSys routers (the models that are at the more expensive end) running for me for 5 years (and then I upgrade to get newer technology like Wireless-N).  Also, keeping the routing equipment in a place that gets good ventilation is important as well because it won't overheat so easily (heating is bad -- be sure to NOT place it near a heat register, on a window sill that gets sunlight, etc.).

Comment: How is this subjective and argumentative? I specifically stated my own experiences using several products and the results I experienced. So, what is subjective about my results? I asked for people to tell me if they had any router whatsoever that was not broken after 180 days time. This is subjective? Plesae explain HOW this is subjective? Plesae don't just scan a question and make assumptions when you havent taken the time to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

Linksys WRT54GL, I have 4 of them (1 as the gateway, 3 in bridged mode) running open source firmware and all are still running non-stop for more than 5 years WITHOUT any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Many other routers I tried either drop connections, lose connections and even (a Digicom) need to be restarted to re-gain an IP after some torrenting (not totally related with ISP), so I really understand what you're saying.

I had a really good time with Buffalo WHR-HP-G54: the firmware was replaced with dd-wrt and it never gave me problems (I used it as a simple router, as an access point and in bridge mode: good performances every time). Now it begins to be a little outdated: I'd give it a go anyway, though.